# Custom Control with Custom Collection Property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls

I have an ASPX Custom Control which is supposed to load it's properties into an internal collection (defined with PersistenceMode.InnerProperty).  Here's the ASPX

```
<cc:CustomControl runat="server">
    <Queries>
        <cc:QueryTypeOne ... />
    </Queries>
</cc:CustomControl>
```

The problem is, when I use the above code, I get a parser error "Type 'CustomControls.QueryCollection' does not have a public property named 'QueryTypeOne'".  (FYI QueryTypeOne inherits a class called Query).  I don't want a public property called QueryTypeOne, I want it to load into the QueryCollection property I have waiting for it!

---

Here's all the relevant code.

CustomControls.CustomControl class has a property called queries

```
<DefaultValue(CType(Nothing, String)),
     MergableProperty(False),
     PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _
    Public Property Queries As QueriesContainerTag
```

And QueriesContainerTag just exists to allow the ASPX engine to get access to the collection (QueryCollection)

```
<ParseChildren(True, "Queries"),
 Serializable()> _
Public Class QueriesContainerTag
    Private _Queries As QueryCollection = Nothing
    Public ReadOnly Property Queries As QueryCollection
        Get
            If _Queries Is Nothing Then
                _Queries = New QueryCollection()
            End If

            Return _Queries
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Where QueryCollection is a custom class that implements ICollection with this signature:

```
Public Class QueryCollection
    Implements IList(Of Query), ICollection(Of Query), IEnumerable(Of Query)
```

Also, oddly enough, if I changed QueriesContainerTag to use a built in list class, everything works perfectly!

```
<ParseChildren(True, "Queries"),
 Serializable()> _
Public Class QueriesContainerTag
    Private _Queries As List(Of Query) = Nothing
    Public ReadOnly Property Queries As List(Of Query)
        Get
            If _Queries Is Nothing Then
                _Queries = New List(Of Query)()
            End If

            Return _Queries
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Did you try putting the Queries property with the QueryCollection right in the custom control and see if that works any better?  Move the <ParseChildren> statement there too.

Comment: It turns out for reasons beyond my comprehension, Microsoft **does not** implement Generic List support for custom control collection properties!  As soon as I added the IList interface, everything started working exactly as expected.

Personally, I don't understand why they did this.  Even more, I would have thought an IList(Of T) (IList<T> for you C# guys) should work automatically everywhere an IList is required.  After all, T will *always* inherit from object.  Such is life I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft **does not** implement Generic List support for custom control collection properties!  As soon as I added the `IList` interface, everything started working exactly as expected.

Personally, I don't understand why they did this.  Even more, I would have thought an `IList(Of T)` (`IList<T>` for you C# guys) should work automatically everywhere an `IList` is required.  After all, T will *always* inherit from object.

Comment: I was rather banging my head against the wall with this one. In the end, I created a custom collection which inherited from Collection<T>. The Collection<T> class already implements IList so now the control works properly.